# Can't update a database record with Spring RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to use Spring Boot and Spring Data Rest to create a simple CRUD rest service, but I can't seem to make the update part work.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-rest version 1.2.2.RELEASE.

This is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String _id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String _firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String _lastName;

    public String getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return _firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return _lastName;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        _firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        _lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

this is my repository definition:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/person-repository")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

My table definition looks like this:

```
create table person
(
   id varchar(64) primary key, 
   first_name varchar(64), 
   last_name varchar(64)
);
```

With this setup I'm able to query the repository (getting an empty result at first):

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository' -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
{ }
```

By the way, I'm using OAuth2 here, hence the Authorization header. This my application main class:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthserverApplication {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Inject
        private AuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
        @Autowired
        private DataSource _dataSource;
        @Autowired
        private JdbcTokenStore _tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(_authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore());
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.jdbc(_dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return _tokenStore;
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(_dataSource);
        }

    }
}
```

I can also add new records:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/' -X POST  -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{ "id" : "12345", "firstName": "Stefan", "lastName": "Meier" }'
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:9999
Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2017 10:26:03 GMT
```

The insert actually worked:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository' -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "id" : "12345",
      "lastName" : "Meier",
      "firstName" : "Stefan",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

But when I try to update an existing record (trying to change the firstName here), it does not work:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345' -X PUT  -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{ "id" : "12345", "firstName": "Peter", "lastName": "Meier" }'
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:9999
Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2017 10:41:38 GMT


$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository' -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"                                                               {
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "id" : "12345",
      "lastName" : "Meier",
      "firstName" : "Stefan",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

I did not reveive an error but the data remains unchanged. I also tried to use PATCH instead of PUT but to no avail.

Deleting a record works though:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository/12345' -X DELETE  -D - -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:9999
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2017 10:42:28 GMT

$ curl 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/person-repository' -H  "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"
{ }
```

There must be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Which version of spring-data-rest are you using?

Comment: Added version info (spring-boot-starter-data-rest version 1.2.2.RELEASE)

Comment: Is trying the latest version an option? It all looks OK. The only thing I found is that you are prefixing your variable names with `_`. Maybe you can try if this is a problem.

Comment: Yes, the _ prefix was the problem. Thanks @MathiasDpunkt for pointing this out.